# Google+ Sign-In for users without a Google+ profile

Tags: google-plus

According to the [official announcement](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/google-sign-in-improvements11.html), Google+ Sign-In now supports users without a Google+ profile.

However, when I visit one the [official examples](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button) from an account without a Google+ profile, it only gives me the option of signing up for Google+.

What's the way to implement this feature? I've been checking the official docs as well but I can't find any references to this topic.

Comment: Any luck on finding an answer yet? I'm facing the same difficulies.

Comment: Yes. Try the new [migration docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#sign-in). What you need to do is to use the profile scope: "Adding the Google+ Sign-In button with the profile scope provides a simple, secure way to authenticate users with access to only the user's basic information. Users are not prompted to create a Google+ profile."

Comment: Yeah, I tried this, but I still get the "create a profile" prompt. Do you use the `GoogleApiClient`? Could you perhaps post a snippet on how you fixed it?

Comment: I posted my code for authentication, could you help me to get it to work? That way we'll create a better resource than the current documentation currently is :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this snippet work shall we?

```
package com.example.googleplusauth;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /*
     * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
     * from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, null)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                startIntentSenderForResult(
                        //result.getIntentSender(),
                        result.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);

            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent. Return to the
                // default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated
                // ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // We've resolved any connection errors. mGoogleApiClient can be used to
        // access Google APIs on behalf of the user.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

}
```